# How toCalculate percentage increase/ decrease in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with 3 rows contain values :

```
Row1 : 5
Row2 : 8
Row3 : 9
```

I wish to calculate the percentage of increase or decrease of : Row2 compared to Row1 , Row3 to Row2 so i would have this table :
The formula to calculate % is : `[Row(n+1) - Row(n)] / Row(2)`

```
     Value   Percentage 
Row1 : 5         -
Row2 : 8        60% (increase compared to Row1) | (8-5)/5
Row3 : 9        12.5%(increase compared to Row2)| (9-8)/8
```

Please suggest the way or a solution .

Thanks all.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the Oracle Analytical function LAG:

Your query will look something like:

```
SELECT ((value - lagv)/lagv) * 100
  FROM (
        SELECT value,
               LAG(value) OVER(ORDER BY <ordering_column>) as lagv
          FROM table1
);
```

To test I ran:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 1 as rnum,
                  5 AS value FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 2 as rnum,
                  8 AS value FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 3 as rnum,
                  9 AS value FROM DUAL
          ) 
SELECT ((value - lagv)/lagv) * 100 AS Percentage
  FROM (
        SELECT value,
               LAG(value) OVER(ORDER BY rnum) as lagv
          FROM t
);
```

It returned:

```
Row  Percentage
  1           
  2          60
  3        12.5
```

As you need to specify an order for the LAG function I have created the rnum column, I assume your table has some sort of ordering column you can use, (otherwise how do you know which rows to compare?).

Hope this helps...

EDIT: This link is pretty useful for learning about Oracle's LEAD and LAG functions. http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/LagLeadAnalyticFunctions.php

Comment: What if there are nulls and you want to only calculate percentage change for the most recent non null value?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @previousRow=0;

SELECT currentRowValue, 
       @previousRowValue:= (SELECT COALESCE(currentRowValue, COUNT(0)) 
                        FROM tableName 
                        WHERE id< t.id 
                        LIMIT 1) AS previousRowValue,
COALESCE((currentRowValue - @previousRowValue) /  @previousRowValue, 0) AS Percentage 

FROM tableName t;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be very helpful for everyone of you could append an explanation on how your code works!